# while using dayjs('2022-10-24 07:35:42 Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z', true).isValid() showing false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, dayjs

Parsing the date '2022-10-24 07:35:42 Z' in dayJS like the following succeeds (is valid) in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

```js
console.log(dayjs('2022-10-24 07:35:42 Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z', true).isValid())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.6/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Firefox shows false because of the space before Z

Comment: Also, `Z` in the format specifier stands for the offset from UTC, given in `±HH:mm` format - which your input value does not contain in that position, it contains the _literal character_ `Z`.

Comment: If you want to use the literal `Z` (zulu time zone / UTC), then you can wrap it in square brackets, [per the documentation](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format): `[Z]`